# Memory issue when calling dispatch_async with local variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, dispatch-async

I am having issues in code when calling dispatch_async. I think that issue is due to ARC reclaiming the object, before it is used in a block, as the method that dispatches it finishes.

```
- (void) method:(SomeClass *) someClass {
  // local variable
  NSNumber *someValue = someClass.somePropertyOnManagedObject;
  dispatch_async(queue, ^() {
    /* call some singleton object passing variable 
     * when access the variable, reference is nil
     */
    [[DashboardFacade sharedInstance] someMethod:someValue];
  });
}
```

After having looking through much documentation, I conclude

- Block accesses no parameters – nothing to discuss
- Block accesses simple type parameters e.g. BOOL, int - these are copied and not a problem
- Block accesses parameter of method that dispatched it - I am not sure, but think
  that this is ok
- Block accesses property of self – as long as self “lives” until the call has finished ok
- Block accesses local variable in method that dispatched it

  - If we use some semaphores such that we wait for the block to return before leaving the method, then all ok
  - Otherwise variable may have been garbage collected before block can use.

I think that the solution is to use `__block` modifier such that ARC retains the variable.

My question is

- Is the above technically correct, e.g. using `__block` will resolve the problem and not introduce other problems?
- Why can't I find this anywhere on the internet/google?

Comment: blocks retain the parameters that you pass in to them. Since `someValue` is being used in the block, a strong reference is being maintained on it. I don't think this is your particular issue.

Comment: __block just makes the variable mutable within the block

Answer (score 0):

> Is the above technically correct, e.g. using __block will resolve the
>   problem and not introduce other problems?

Yes it's technically correct, `__block`, on ARC, allows you to change the variable (in this case to where its pointing, since it's a `NSNumber *`), that was declared outside the block context.

> Why can't I find this anywhere on the internet/google?

I think the problem is not related to this particular place of your code, but something else.

Answer (score 0):

`someValue` inside the block can be nil only if it is nil after this assignment:

```
NSNumber *someValue = someClass.somePropertyOnManagedObject;
```

Blocks retain objects that are being captured by the blocks as a result of those variables being used inside the blocks. And it doesn’t matter if it is self or a local variable from the scope that is visible to the block.